# Get child node values at XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I try to get child nodes' values of XElement using C#. XElement block is below. My purpose is to get values at 'c0' nodes. How can I do this?

```
// client is Orion SDK (SWIS) client.
XElement xe = client.QueryXml("select Uri FROM Orion.Pollers WHERE NetObjectID = 15", null);
```

XElement result block:

```
<queryResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.solarwinds.com/2007/08/informationservice">
<template>
<resultset>
  <column name="Uri" type="String" ordinal="0" /> 
</resultset>
</template>
<data>
    <row>
        <c0>swis://solarwinds./Orion/Orion.Pollers/PollerID=55</c0> 
    </row>
    <row>
        <c0>swis://solarwinds./Orion/Orion.Pollers/PollerID=56</c0> 
    </row>
    <row>
        <c0>swis://solarwinds./Orion/Orion.Pollers/PollerID=57</c0> 
    </row>
    <row>
        <c0>swis://solarwinds./Orion/Orion.Pollers/PollerID=58</c0> 
    </row>
  </data>
</queryResult>
```

Comment: give us your code it will be lot easier to update it rather then us starting from scratch

Comment: Sorry, I forgot paste that code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Code block is below.

```
    XElement xe = client.QueryXml("SELECT Uri FROM Orion.Pollers WHERE NetObjectID = 15", null);

    IList<XElement> indexedElements = xe.Elements().ToList();

    foreach (var item in ((XElement)xe.Elements().ToList()[1]).Elements().ToList())
    {
        try
        {
            //Do something with 
            //item.Value
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw exc;
        }


    }
```